# self.navigationController == nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I tried to make a simple switch view function but it did not work
then I tried to see if the second view is assigned and it was fine.
The thing is that my `self.navigationControler` is `nil` .
How do i fix that ?

```
ViewController2 *hs=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Highscore"];
if(self.navigationController==nil)
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"YOur Message" message:@"Your description"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
}


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:hs animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to present the current view controller from a UINavigationController

```
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:Your_Current_View_Controller];

//Now present controller in any way you want
```

After that your self.navigationController will not be nil anymoer

Comment: I can switch Your_Curent_View_Controller only for self . there is no nil this way but the button doesnt work. if i get you right i should switch it whit WievControler1